# Simple .h file troubles

Tags: c++, header, makefile

I have a simple simple simple .h file

```
#ifndef _HEAD
#define _HEAD

void GetNextMove(char playerSymbol, int &row, int &col);

#endif
```

included in a .cpp file with `#include "head.h"` which is is included in another .cpp file with `#include "file.cpp"`. I keep getting the error

```
/tmp/ccfN3b2g.o:Proj1Aux.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `GetNextMove(char, int&, int&)'
/tmp/ccDzQLIi.o:Proj1.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

does anyone know what would cause that? I thought putting the `#infdef...` would stop repetition.

Comment: You shouldn't ever `#include` a .cpp file.  Why are you doing that?  It's not complaining about your header, it's complaining that you have `GetNextMove` in both Proj1.cpp and Proj1Aux.cpp.

Comment: But if take out the `#include` it will complain that the function wasn't defined because the prototype isn't there. I'm sorry I'm brand new to C++, even when I compile them at the same time.

Comment: Use `#include "head.h"` in both of your `.cpp` files.  Don't include one `.cpp` file in the other `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0):

Including one `.cpp` file in another `.cpp` file is a very advanced technique that's best avoided until you thoroughly understand the normal use of `#include`. Include only header files for now. If you get errors where a prototype is not seen for a function declared in another file, put it in a header file that's included by both `.cpp` files.

Answer (score 0):

- So your include structure is like below.

`head.h` ---------> `file.cpp` --------------> `xxxxx.cpp`

- So I guess `file.cpp` has the implementation for `GetNextMove` function.
- Then `xxxxx.cpp` doesn't differentiate the declaration and definition of the function.
- It consider declaration(`head.h`) and definition(`file.cpp`) both as  definitions, And shows you this error.

As solutions:

- Do not include `*.cpp` files.
- Try to keep only function declarations in the header(`*.h`) files.